# Copy dll to another project in post-build but SolutionDir is level down

Tags: visual-studio, copy, post-build

I want to copy dll from a project to another in same solution in post-build, but all the solution Directory doesn't help me and nothing in Marcos did.
for example:

pro1 in C:/A/B/Pro1

pro2 in c:/A/B/Pro2

solution in C:/A/B/SolutionFolder

I want to copy **pro1.dll** to **pro2/bin**
The problem is the SolutionDir is **C:/A/B/SolutionFolder**
I need to go one level up. I tried these and others nothing helped!

> xcopy "$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)" "$(SolutionDir)..\Pro1\bin)"
>
> xcopy "$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)" "$(SolutionDir)" "(..\Pro1\bin)"
>   with () and without them

Edit:
And I need to copy this file to 2 directions not only one. I tried && but it didnt work